# Broken Ajax and JS while testing out a CDN on three different directories on a Magento Build

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, prototypejs

This is a Magento build. I believe some link or directory structure may have broken. All my Ajax is broken and my console is showing the error below.

I think it has something to do with `ajax_pager.js:101` which references the `getBaseUrl`.

Do I may need an updated version of Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7.3

Error log is saying

```
Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead
```

---

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at klass.prepareUrlForMana (ajax_pager.js:101)
        at klass.ajaxProductsUpdate (ajax_pager.js:70)
        at ajax_pager.js:59
        at responder (prototype.js:5598)
```

I've right clicked on the prototype.js and ajax_pager.js files and they appear to be linked correctly still.

**ajax_pager.js**

```
    url.substr(this.config.getBaseUrl(url).length);  LINE 101


    var preparedUrl = this.prepareUrlForMana(this.listConfig.nextBunchUrl);   LINE 70


        // define if current offset scrolled to checkpoint
        if(scrolledToCheckPoint) {
            _this.ajaxProductsUpdate();  LINE 59
        }
```

**prototype.js**

```
  } else {
    responder = function(event) {
      Event.extend(event, element);
      handler.call(element, event);
    };
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to further investigate.

[image: Base URL should just take on BASE URL]

Comment: A good way to investigate on these kind of issues, is opening the Chrome Network Inspecter and look at the requests. With those, you will be able to see if your content is getting loaded like you want.

Comment: it would help if you could show us the code that was producing that error?

Comment: I think it has something to do with ajax_pager.js:101which references the getBaseUrl. Since I've changed this I feel like it's still cached some how or some where. Maybe I'll try purging the CDN cache.

Comment: @sauntimo I've added some code.

Comment: Well, `this.config.getBaseUrl(url)` is clearly undefined, does that config object have that method, is it working, and what is the value of url that you're passing it?

Comment: @sauntimo this is a magento build so it should just take on whatever is being entered. See image above.

Comment: well, except something is going wrong because you're getting undefined. can you log out the value of `url` before you call the fn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150357/discussion-between-singleton-and-sauntimo).